# jQuery displaying escaped output from Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, jQuery 1.6.2

HTML

```
<textarea id="photo-42-9" class="comment_box">Write a comment...</textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$('#newsfeed').delegate('.comment_box', 'keydown', function (event){
   if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    var $this = $(event.target);
    $.post('/comments', { title: ..., description: ... }, function(response) { $(response).insertBefore($this); }, "script");
  }
});
```

Rails

```
comments_controller.rb    
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.js
    end
  end

create.js.erb
"<%= escape_javascript( render 'show_comments') %>"
```

`render 'show_comments'` returns a `<div>...</div>` that I wish to insert before `textarea`. What I found is that the special characters escaped in the output aren't rendered properly by JS, ideas? This is what it looks like currently in HTML after `insertBefore`

```
<div class="\&quot;comment\&quot;">(Bob less than a minute ago) beautiful day<\/div></div>
```

I just noticed that an extra `</div>` is added to the end of the output, seemingly by jQuery because this is what `create.js.erb` spits out as shown in Firebug console response

```
'<div class=\"comment\">(Bob less than a minute ago) beautiful day<\/div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<%= raw escape_javascript( render 'show_comments') %>
```

Comment: Good suggestion but that didn't work, it had the same result, I have updated my question with the output.